# React Router Dom Link in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm quite new to React in general so I apologise in advance if there is a simple solution.

I have two components:

Dashboard
--Sidebar (Called in Dashboard)

I have a path set up in Dashboard, and Links in my Sidebar. When I click a link the URL changes, but the Dashboard doesn't re-render, so it only changes on a page refresh. My question is, is there a way through react-router that I can set my Dashboard to re-render on click of a Link in Sidebar?

Import

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Dashboard Component:

```
<DashboardSidebar />
<BrowserRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardLanding} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={ViewUsers} />
        <Route path="/project" component={ViewProjects} />
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Dashboard Sidebar Component

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Link
        to="/"
        className="nav-link" 
        onClick={this.navigation} 
    >
    Link</Link>
    <Link
        to="/profile"
        className="nav-link" 
        onClick={this.navigation} 
    >
    Link</Link>
    <Link
        to="/project"
        className="nav-link" 
        onClick={this.navigation} 
    >
    Link</Link>
<BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for another  in you SideBar component. wrap it with a div or maybe a Fragment.

Comment: I've moved the sidebar to above the dashboard as you suggested, unfortunately, the component still does not render

Comment: Do you still have two <BrowserRouter> in your code?

Comment: Yes, should they both be nested under the same <BrowserRouter> ?

Comment: No, you only need your <Route> tags under the <BrowserRouter>, not the <Link>, links can be any where in your app, so just remove the <BrowserRouter> around your <Link> tag and put a <div> instead

Comment: When I remove the <BrowserRouter> tags around <Link> the whole app breaks and I get this error:
`You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

Comment: Yeah just as I said, It's a little hard to post codes in comments, I'll just share a gist with you

Comment: https://gist.github.com/prithweedas/2ceffa8d58fb9dbc4e6c3543ff024ea6
Here's a link to the gist

Comment: Thanks for the gist that was really useful, but it returns a new error.
`A <Router> may have only one child element`

Here is my dashboard component:
https://gitlab.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/eo023/client-management-system/blob/projectUserLink/frontend/src/components/Dashboard.Component.js#L126
Sidebar Component
https://gitlab.mi.hdm-stuttgart.de/eo023/client-management-system/blob/projectUserLink/frontend/src/components/DashboardSidebar.Component.js#L30

Comment: Yeah that was my bad, forgot about that, updated the gist, if `<></>` this syntax doesn't work for you, just use a <div> instead of these

Comment: You are welcome, if this helped you, kindly upvote and accept the answer to help others identify the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Maybe problem is in:
   **last line of code BrowserRouter** you have open tag instead of close.
2. Second soluction can be that try to change wrapper BrowserRouter **with div tag.**

Comment: Sorry, the first problem is only from me making a mistake copying and pasting neater code! I have also done as @prithweedas suggested below and moved all of the sidebar component code to my dashboard, however, the component still does not rerender.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserRouter needed to have DashboardboardSidebar component inside it and all wrapped in one child.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<>
<DashboardSidebar />
<div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={DashboardLanding} />
    <Route path="/profile" component={ViewUsers} />
    <Route path="/project" component={ViewProjects} />
</div>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

eoan! Here is how I use this logic.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

function ParentComponent() {
  return(
    <Router>
       <div>
         <SomeNavBar />
         <SomeFeed />
       </div>
    </Router>
  )
};

export default ParentComponent;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function SomeNavBar(){
  return(
    <Router>
       <div>
         <Link to="/">Home</Link>
         <Link to="/about"></Link>>
       </div>
    </Router>
  )
};

export default SomeNavBar;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------

import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function SomeFeed(){
  return(
    <Switch>
       <Route path="/" exact>
            <PostUpdates />
            <SomeOtherPost />
            ...
       </Route> 
       <Route path="/about" >
            <Welcome />
            <Description />
            ...
       </Route> 
    </Switch>
  )
};

export default SomeFeed;
```

Just wrap parent component.